# What set of RxJava operators can I use on a PublishSubject that delays all but first item then skips all but last item during the delay?

Tags: rx-java

I'm trying to construct an RxJava sequence on a PublishSubject that has the following properties:

1. The subscriber receives the first value with no delay.
2. All subsequent values are delayed by 1 second after the previous delivery to the subscriber.
3. If >1 value is observed during that time, all but the last are thrown away.

The marbleish diagram would be:

```
1   2   3   4   5       2   3   4

< ----- 1 second ------><--- 1 second ----->

1                       5                   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out [`throttleLatest`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#throttlelatest) is what I was looking for.